# Intellij basic complete ctrl + space is not working on macOS

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, hotkeys

I am running *IntelliJ IDEA* on my macOS Big Sur and <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> for basic complete does not seem to work.
I looked under *Preferences* / *Keymap* / *Code Completion* / *Basic*, and it seems in order.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also still relevant on Monterey

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Found out that the OS itself has this already taken.

I disabled the shortcut on System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Input Sources -> Tick off "Select the previous input source" and it did the trick.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I wonder which update broke this...

Comment: Still not working for me. It works in my windows machine, but not in Mac OS.

Comment: Thanks!, it worked for me with a USA input source

Comment: Thank! That was my problem (having Spanish and US English)

Comment: thank you very much, you saved my time and efforts

Comment: Lifesaver !

Answer (score 1):

On Ventura it worth checking the Spotlight item also

[image: Screenshot]